# add a keyboard shortcut action to Lead object

Tags: action

Hi I am very new to Salesforce and I was wondering if there was any way to make a keyboard shortcut action in the Leads object? I know that there is a "Behavior Option" to execute javascript but the javascript is only called for OnClick for a button or link.

any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You can use Javascript to listen for keyboard shortcuts but that wouldn't really be a Salesforce issue.

Comment: thanks for the response. I know how to listen for action events but I was wondering where to put the javascript for that. I was confused because I thought that the javascript for an action was only for OnClick

Comment: JavaScript can also be written into Visualforce pages. If you absolutely need JS on the lead pages, you could override the Lead View and Edit screens with Visualforce and embed your JS there.

Comment: Or you can just add the visualforce page in the standard view layout and set the height to 0px or something so that it's not visible